# Issue with function to determine if an int contains a certain number

Tags: c++

I am on an assignment in c++. This is my assignment:

> The keypad on your oven is used to enter the desired baking temperature and is arranged like the digits on a phone. Unfortunately, the digits 1, 4, and 7 do not work.
> When a recipe calls for a temperature that can't be entered (due to keys not working), you want to substitute a temperature that can be entered.
>
> Write a program that takes a desired temperature as an input from the user. The temperature must be between 0 and 999 degrees.
>
> If the desired temperature does not contain 1, 4, or 7, then display the desired temperature. If it contains 1, 4, or 7, compute and display the next largest temperature that doesn't contain 1, 4, or 7.
>
> For example, if the desired temperature is 450, then the program should output 500. Similarly, if the desired temperature is 375, then the program should output 380.
>
> In your program, include and use a function named "containsDigit" declared as below. If the entered number contains a digit, the function should return true. Otherwise, the function should return false.

The question I have is there a way to write a function that searches the input for 1,4,7 or a certain value?
I am a beginner.
It is not finished I am trying to write each section one by one and this is where I am stuck.

Here is what I have so far.

```
// Module1assignment.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int number;
int digits;
int temp;




bool containsDigits(int number, int digits)

{
    if (bool containsDigits = false)
        cout << "Please enter a valid number" << endl;
        cin >> temp;
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cout << "Please enter the temperature." << endl;
    cin >> temp;

    //This is to make sure the users enters the temp within the desired range//

    if (temp < 0 && temp >999)
    {
        bool containsDigits(int number, int digits);
        cout << "Please enter a valid temperature. " << endl;
        cin >> temp;
     }
    //This is where I want to write a function to search the input for a 1,4and,7//
    //My ideal is if digit = 1 then it changes to 2 if digit = 4 then it changes to 5
    and if digit =7 it changes to 8. That is my ideal. Is it possible to do this 
    without dividing the input into three separate inputs//

    else if (temp )
    
    


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What logic you have tried till now? SO is not here to write code for you.

Comment: In comment I mentioned I wanted to make if digit = 1 then digit =2 but I meant to put if it =1 then change to 0 and for 4 and 7 still change to the next numbers 4 and 8. I just need to if there is something I can use to search for certain numbers.

Comment: Convert the value to a string, search for individual characters.

Comment: Start with something simpler, like a function that takes a number and returns that number plus 1. But first read your book, from the beginning, and do all the exercises that you skipped.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
/**this function should check wheter number have the digit digit**/
bool containsDigit(int number, int digit) 
{
    //let's say number is 982, then...
    int a = number/100; //a is 9
    int b = (number/10)%10; //b is 8
    int c = number%10; //c is 2
    if (a==digit || b==digit || c==digit)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Then, in main, you should have:

```
cout << "Please enter the temperature." << endl;
cin >> temp;

//This is to make sure the users enters the temp within the desired range//

if (temp < 0 && temp >999)
{
    bool containsDigits(int number, int digits);
    cout << "Please enter a valid temperature. " << endl;
    cin >> temp;
 }

 while(containsDigit(temp, 1) || containsDigit(temp, 4) || containsDigit(temp, 7))
     temp++; //keeps incrementing temp until it doesn't contain 1 ,4 nor 7

 cout << "The right temperature is :" << temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd convert the int to string, then change 1->2, 4->5, 7->8.

```
bool isSpoiltDigit (char digit){

    return digit == '1' || digit =='2' || digit =='3';
}

char convertToNextHighest (char input){

      switch (input){
         case '1': return '2';
         case '4': return '5';
         case '5': return '8'; 
}

int convertToNextHighest (int temperature){

   ostringstream oss;
   oss<< temperature;

   string s = oss.str();
   size_t size = s.size();

   if (size ==1){
      s[0] = convertToNextHighest (s[0]);
      return stoi (s);
   }else if (size ==2){

      if ( isSpoiltDigit (s[0])){ 
          s[0] =  convertToNextHighest (s[0]);
          s[1] = '0';
      }else {
          s[1] = convertToNextHighest (s[1]);
      }
      int result = stoi(s);
      return result;
   }else { //if (size ==3) 

      if ( isSpoiltDigit (s[0])){ 

          s[0] =  convertToNextHighest (s[0]);
          s[1] = '0';
          s[2] = '0';
      }else if  isSpoiltDigit (s[1])){ 

          s[1] =  convertToNextHighest (s[1]);
          s[2] = '0'; 
      } else {
          s[2] = convertToNextHighest (s[1]);

      }
      int result = stoi(s);
      return result;
   }
```

}

Comment: This is wrong. If temp is 199 this would produce 299, whilst the desired output is 200.

Comment: @LGenzelis, that is true. I have reset all the child numbers to '0'.